# Is there something wrong with my JS if statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Working with JS, Jquery, Bootstrap 3. Rather than create multiple modals that are individually triggered, I wrote a script to fill the modal based on the content that is being embedded, and then fill the modal with the embedded content.

Modal Markup:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="ideasmodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
<span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
<h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"></h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body" id="library-content"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Triggers:

```
<a data-frame="http://path.to.url" data-content="embed" class="btn btn-primary modaltrigger" role="button">Learn More</a>
<a data-frame="http://path/to/image.png" data-content="image" class="btn btn-primary modaltrigger" role="button">Learn More</a>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$( ".modaltrigger" ).click(function(){
    var dataContent = this.getAttribute("data-content");
    if (dataContent = "embed") {
        var modalClass = 'embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9';
        var modalContent = this.getAttribute("data-frame");
        var modalBody = document.createElement("IFRAME");
        var embedContainer = document.createElement("DIV");
        embedContainer.setAttribute("class", modalClass);
        modalBody.setAttribute("src", modalContent)
        modalBody.setAttribute("class", "embed-responsive-item");
        modalBody.setAttribute( "frameborder", "0");
        document.getElementById("library-content").appendChild(embedContainer);
        embedContainer.appendChild(modalBody);
        $('#ideasmodal').modal('show');
    }
    else if (dataContent = "image") {
        var modalContent = this.getAttribute("data-frame");
        var modalBody = document.createElement("IMG");
        modalBody.setAttribute("src", modalContent);
        modalBody.setAttribute("class", "img-responsive");
        document.getElementById("library-content").appendChild(modalBody);
        $('#ideasmodal').modal('show');
    }
});
$( ".close").click(function(){
    document.getElementById("library-content").innerHTML= "";
});
});
```

So what's happening on the live site is when I click on the link with the data-content="image", the site is still generating an iframe vs. directly embedding the image (the ELSE) of my if statement. It's not a huge deal, except I don't want to be confined to the ratios defined by bootstrap's responsive embed classes - my images are not always going to fit that 4:3 or 16:9 ratio.

I'm very new to JS, so apologies if I'm missing something very obvious. I've run this with a console/debugger and I'm not getting any errors thrown at me other than that toString is not allowed (which, from search this site I can see to ignore it for now as it's a Flash issue).

Comment: `=` should be `===` when doing a comparison... `=` will set the variable

Comment: Consider using a tool like http://jshint.com to help you find common errors.

Comment: I've never seen that site before. THANK YOU! It's getting bookmarked

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You only have 1 equals in both your statements

```
if (dataContent == "embed") {
    //logic
} else if (dataContent == "image") {
    //logic
}
```

Answer (score 1):

should be == not =.

```
if (dataContent == "embed") {
    var modalClass = 'embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9';
    var modalContent = this.getAttribute("data-frame");
    var modalBody = document.createElement("IFRAME");
    var embedContainer = document.createElement("DIV");
    embedContainer.setAttribute("class", modalClass);
    modalBody.setAttribute("src", modalContent)
    modalBody.setAttribute("class", "embed-responsive-item");
    modalBody.setAttribute( "frameborder", "0");
    document.getElementById("library-content").appendChild(embedContainer);
    embedContainer.appendChild(modalBody);
    $('#ideasmodal').modal('show');
}
else if (dataContent == "image") {
```

= is used for assignment == is used for comparison.